# X-ray structure analysis mirrored coordinates?

Tags: stereochemistry, molecular-structure, chirality, crystallography, x-ray-diffraction

How to ensure, that X-ray crystallography structure analysis was done right to provide correct, non-mirrored atomic coordinates?

---

*Example:* Following [Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Methamphetamine_molecule_from_xtal_ball.png),

[image]

is generated from data taken from the article [Redetermination of (+)-methamphetamine hydro­chloride at 90 K](https://doi.org/10.1107/S1600536808011550).

However, the structure presented by the [CIF file](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/sendcif?lh2608sup1) represents (*R*)-methamphetamine, known to be [levomethamphetamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levomethamphetamine), (–)-methamphetamine,

[image: Fig.2 (R)-methamphetamine]

the enantiomer of “native” methamphetamine, [dextromethamphetamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextromethamphetamine), (+)-methamphetamine, identified as (*S*)-methamphetamine.

[image: Fig.2 (S)-methamphetamine]

Also, the article does not claim that the absolute configuration of (dextro)methamphetamine has been for so long mistaken and that they come with revolutionary discovery, rather are just focusing on some inter-atomic distances. (Also the “traditional absolute configuration” has been verified e.g. by synthesis from D-phenylalanine.)

---

As far as I have known, X-ray structure analysis was unable to provide absolute configuration info. But technology evolves. Can one determine from the experimental data, that it's supposed to be “absolute” or “relative” only (so that the coordinates presented can be mirrored)?

**UPDATE**: After some comments, I should emphasize that the example is just for an example (of case where the reported coordinates seem to be mirrored; I don’t know how rare or common it is), but can be used as an example in the answer as well, of course (e.g. CIF file analysis, e.g. explaining the Flack parameter value meaning, …)

And a subquestion: When hydrogen positions are provided, does it imply that the configuration is absolute? (I presume that the coordinates can still be mirrored even in such case; I mean “uncertain z-coordinate orientation”.)

Comment: X-ray ***does*** provide absolute configuration info. It is just that with Mo radiation and light-atom structure it won't be reliable enough.

Comment: As Ivan Neretin comments x-ray diffraction is the definitive method to obtain structure. However, x-rays are scattered off the electrons in an atom and this makes it very difficult to detect H atoms, and hence your question. Neutron diffraction could be used instead.

Comment: @porphyrin Hydrogen positions are irrelevant to the configuration determination, as the other substituents are carbon and nitrogen based. (Also in the formula there are no hydrogens, yet it’s stereochemically unambiguous ;) )

Comment: Ah yes, I mis-read the last two line structures.   In that case as long as you have pure crystalline substances x-ray diffraction should be the technique to use.

Comment: In the linked crystal structure all atom positions (including hydrogen) have been refined, there is no doubt that the measured compound is (*R*)-*N*-methyl-1-phenylpropan-2-amine.What they were sold for measuring the compound is another question; "The material for this work was purchased from Sigma-Aldrich and was used without any further purification." They did not specify they  how they assigned (+), so I'd guess that was on the label. I don't really understand what the question is; obviously you cannot ensure that the people did their jobs right without checking the raw data.

Comment: @Martin: It's just an example. But, I wonder why would they order more expensive enantiomer for the study of a parameter independent of the absolute configuration. However, the price difference is small. And, S.-A. has (+), (-) (sic! typo), or (±) in the names explicitly. (Sometimes both abs. and opt., e.g. S(+)-Methamphetamine solution. I’ve checked the rotation is same for free base and salt.)

Comment: I am confused. Where did you get the information that they were not studying the absolute configuration? I read that the only purpose of this measurement were to determine the nuclear positions. Diffraction will give you the unit cell; and depending on the quality of what you obtained/bought, that will give you the absolute configuration(s). After solving the crystal structure with the confidence necessary to publish it, you know the absolute configuration of what you have measured. What I find bothering is that they do not name the absolute configuration at all.

Comment: @Martin 1. It seemed to me that they were interested primarily in the $\ce{N-H\bond{...}Cl}$ distance. 2. Naive layman (likely wrong) thought process that can lead to abs. config. doubt: X-ray diffraction is recorded on the plate. If it’s “orthographic projection” (not perspective) the absolute z-coordinate values should be impossible to obtain.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Standard diffraction experiments do not give absolute configuration, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I have known, X-ray structure analysis was unable to provide absolute configuration info.

Routine X-ray structure analysis might not, but there are ways to determine absolute configurations from X-ray data.

The reason that routine X-ray structure analysis does not distinguish between enantiomers is that diffraction intensities show inversion symmetry, or obey Fridel's law. If you rotate the crystal by 180 degrees, you expect the same diffraction image. The phases, however, will be distinct.

[image]

Friedel's law breaks down for anomalous diffraction, which occurs when the wavelength of the X-rays is close to the absorption edge of one of the atoms in the structure. This has been used in protein crystallography to find positions of selenium for seleno-methionine derivatized proteins (MAD and SAD phasing methods). However, as Ivan mentions in the comments, the elements present in this molecule would not be near their absorption edges in a standard lab experiment using Mo-radiation.

> When hydrogen positions are provided, does it imply that the configuration is absolute?

No, that just indicates that the resolution was sufficiently high to model hydrogen atoms. You can have ultra high resolution without resolving absolute configuration.

> How to ensure, that X-ray crystallography structure analysis was done right to provide correct, non-mirrored atomic coordinates?

In a standard experiment, where Friedel mates are averaged, both given coordinates and their mirror image are valid solutions that fit to the diffraction experiment.

If you look at the diffraction data ([CIF file](https://journals.iucr.org/e/issues/2008/05/00/lh2608/lh2608Isup2.hkl)), they did not measure anomalous data. The headings are "h,k,l, Fc-squared, Fo-squared, sigma(Fo-squared) and status flag".

#### Finding the absolute configuration

From classical to cutting edge, here are some strategies:

1. Derivatize the sample with a chiral substance of known configuration: In this case, you could make an amide with lactic acid purified from a biological sample. You will get a diastereomer, and the lactic acid will tell you the absolute configuration.
2. Use anomolous diffraction, i.e. choose a wavelength close to an absorption edge of nitrogen or carbon, which would be tricky. Other elements are more suitable because they show a larger effect, and at wavelengths that are easier to handle.
3. Measure the phases. Using a free electron laser or a triple-beam experiment, measure some or all phases of the diffraction intensities.